# Random Forest Regression - How do I analyse its performance? - python, sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm struggling to assess the performance of my random forest - I've looked at the mean relative error, but I'm not sure if it's a good indicator. What are some things to check for?

Also, how should I optimise my hyperparameters? 
I've used  `rf.score(X_test,y_test)`  R2, but is that really the only thing I should rely on when doing regressions? I had a look into out of bag scores, but I'm not sure how to interpret them.

May your optima be global and your hyper-parameters optimized :)

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000,max_depth=5,random_state = 0)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train);

predictions = rf.predict(X_test)


errors = abs((predictions - y_test)/y_test)
print('Mean Relative Error:', round(np.mean(errors), 2))
```

Comment: Please [read here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#ooberr) to get some understanding of the theory behind random forests, and what methods are available to assess a forest's accuracy.  I don't know your Python API at all, but there should be things available like OOB error and Gini importance.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good reference! I read about the Gini index etc. before, but I'm not sure how to implement it in sklearn. Would you even use sklearn?@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: A lot of data people use Python.  Yes, if you need to do random forests in production, then your package seems like a good option.  Some data scientists are mainly offline, in which they might do this in R instead.

Comment: Could you state the problem you are working on? This would hep in selecting a suitable metric. However,  I think to investigate the performance of the algorithm you should try [cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

Answer (score 12):

For regression model (do not confuse with the classifier model) you can evaluate MAE, MSE, MAPE and RMSE from `sklearn`:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics

print('Mean Absolute Error (MAE):', metrics.mean_absolute_error(gt, pred))
print('Mean Squared Error (MSE):', metrics.mean_squared_error(gt, pred))
print('Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE):', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(gt, pred)))
mape = np.mean(np.abs((gt - pred) / np.abs(gt)))
print('Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE):', round(mape * 100, 2))
print('Accuracy:', round(100*(1 - mape), 2))
```

Comment: Today, RMSE and MAPE can be calculated with scikit learn library functions (version >= 0.24). They are more robust against errors like zero devisions. I just created an extension for the latest version based on your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209358/2056125

Answer (score 7):

In order to extend the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58167031/2056125) from [Igor Ezersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10780574/igor-ezersky), there are a lot more functions implemented in scikit learn for model and performance evaluations. A complete list of all scoring parameters are provided in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). Also, some metrics like RMSE and MAPE don't need manual calculations any more (scikit learn version >= 0.24) because they are implemented as library functions. Also, they are much more secure against errors (like zero devisions).

An extended version of the mentioned answer with all currently available metrics for regressions might look like this:

```
from sklearn import metrics

y_true = [...] # Your real values / test labels
y_pred = [...] # The predictions from your ML / RF model

print('Mean Absolute Error (MAE):', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred))
print('Mean Squared Error (MSE):', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
print('Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE):', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred, squared=False))
print('Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE):', metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred))
print('Explained Variance Score:', metrics.explained_variance_score(y_true, y_pred))
print('Max Error:', metrics.max_error(y_true, y_pred))
print('Mean Squared Log Error:', metrics.mean_squared_log_error(y_true, y_pred))
print('Median Absolute Error:', metrics.median_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred))
print('R^2:', metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred))
print('Mean Poisson Deviance:', metrics.mean_poisson_deviance(y_true, y_pred))
print('Mean Gamma Deviance:', metrics.mean_gamma_deviance(y_true, y_pred))
```

If you need more information about the respective metrics, have a look in the [scikit learn User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics).

Answer (score -3):

You can also add these two more metrics:

```python
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
```

accuracy_score(my_class_column, my_forest_train_prediction)
    confusion_matrix(my_test_data, my_prediction_test_forest)

Also the probability for each prediction can be added:

```python
my_classifier_forest.predict_proba(variable 1, variable n)
```

Comment: Please be aware that the answer talks about performance metrics for *classification*, while the question is about *regression*.